# sock_create() in kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I was looking in to `__sock_create()` code to get better understanding of the kernel's internal machinery and found that the kernel calls `try_module_get()` twice; here is a snippet:

```
static int __sock_create(struct net *net, int family, int type, int protocol, struct socket **res, int kern)
{
   sock = sock_alloc();
   ...
   if (!try_module_get(pf->owner))
      goto out_release;

   err = pf->create(net, sock, protocol);
   ...

   if (!try_module_get(sock->ops->owner))
      goto out_module_busy

   ...
}
```

Essentially if socket relevant callbacks are in a module, then whenever every `socket()` from the user space will bump the module's reference count twice. What's the rationale for such behaviour?

Comment: I guess you really must ask the original authors not a global audience. on a programming QA site. Maybe codereview?

Answer (score 1):

You have two modules, hence two reference count increments.
One is Packet family module , second is socket type module.

Checkout http://www.haifux.org/lectures/217/netLec5.pdf for reference.

Comment: Can you explain, what two modules are you referring to?

Comment: PF can be INET for ipv4 and INET6 for ipv6, socket type can be udp , tcp. The exact modules are dependant of the arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes more sense now. Later in the code __sock_create() invokes module_put(pf->owner) that drops one refcnt, so essentially (assuming everything goes well) by the end of socket creation procedure we have exactly 1 reference set per module, am I correct?